# FrameLayout.LayoutParams doesn't work

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to avoid the following situation in the activity( [screen shot of the activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9DVU.png)). When I add the margins using setMargins it does not work. I have tried adding margins via xml code and the end result is achieved but it very time consuming and it can't be guaranteed that it will work for all devices. How can i do it in code?

Here is the code.

```
package com.example.android.tourguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class TouristAttractions extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private NavigationView mNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_item);
    /*
      Finding the Toolbar that is defined in activity_main.xml via the id toolbar.
      Note:The following three lines should be repeated for all the activities that are opened from the MainActivity. Also the toolbar should have an orientation
      which is not zero.
     */
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_for_menu_items);
    /*
       Setting the action bar as the toolbar defined in the above code line
     */
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    /*
      Setting the title text color of the app bar.
     */
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_of_text_of_app_bar));
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    /*
       Finding the drawerLayout so that when the user clicks on the menu item of the navigation drawer it should close as we invoke the method closeDrawers()
     */
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.home_menu) {
                /*
                Opening the home class that is the MainActivity when the Tourist Home menu button is clicked.
                 */
                Intent intentToOpenHomeClass = new Intent(TouristAttractions.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentToOpenHomeClass);
            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.entertainment_menu) {
                Intent intentToOpenEntertainmentClass = new Intent(TouristAttractions.this, Entertainment.class);
                startActivity(intentToOpenEntertainmentClass);
            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.gardens_menu) {
                Intent intentToOpenGardenClass = new Intent(TouristAttractions.this, Garden.class);
                startActivity(intentToOpenGardenClass);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_for_menu_items);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_for_menu_items);
    AdapterForFragmentOfTouristAttraction adapterForFragmentOfTouristAttraction = new AdapterForFragmentOfTouristAttraction(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterForFragmentOfTouristAttraction);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, toolbar.getHeight(), 0, 0);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    /*
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) will make the icon clickable and add the < at the left of the icon.

     */
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    /*
    Enabling the menu icon of the navigation.However note we are simply adding the menu icon however clicking on the icon does absolutely nothing.
     */
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.baseline_menu_white_24);

}

}
```

Comment: Just set the layout in xml. It's not very time consuming.

Comment: but that doesn't guarantee that it will work for all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it might be a better idea to use a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation, a RelativeLayout, or a ConstraintLayout to position views below one another. In more exotic use cases even a CoordinatorLayout might be better suited.

FrameLayouts are mostly used to simply overlay views on one another, without depdendencies between them.

---

This said, the issue you are facing occurs because you use `toolbar.getHeight()` right after adding the view, which will always be `0`. Try attaching a debugger and see for yourself!

The reason is that Android needs a bit of time to `measure -> layout -> draw` its views, and if you call `getHeight` right after adding the layout it will not have done either of those steps, leaving the values uninitialized, at `0`.

There are ways around that, but again, you would be better off using a different layout alltogether. If you insist on using a FrameLayout the cleanest approach would be to extend it and create your own, where you can measure and layout the view yourself. The hacky, hard to maintain, and confusing approach would be to use `ViewTreeObserver` to listen for the changes and react to them. This is bad because you have to wait for a full layout pass before you trigger yet another one.

---

Don't use a FrameLayout here.

Answer (score 0):

You havn't Done

```
yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
```